# Filter and sort in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to filter and sort data in my Kind="sensordata"
in Google datastore

```
Query<com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity> query 
= Query.newEntityQueryBuilder()
       .setKind("sensordata")                               
       .setFilter(PropertyFilter.eq("deviceguid",deviceGuid))
       .setOrderBy(OrderBy.desc("timestamp"))
       .build();
```

All my fields are indexed.
If i remove either of .SetFilter or .setOrderBy, its working fine.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Thanks
Sandy

Comment: What are the problem symptoms?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect either an index for deviceguid+timestamp is missing from your [datastore-indexes.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/indexref) or [index.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/indexref-yaml):

```
<datastore-index kind="Sensordata" ancestor="false">
    <property name="deviceguid" direction="asc" />
    <property name="timestamp" direction="desc" />
</datastore-index>
```

or you haven't [uploaded it](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/indexconfig#updating_indexes).

The reason is that queries with simple filters or sort orders can use automatic indexes but ["Other forms of query require their indexes to be specified in the index configuration file"](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/indexes#index-configuration)